# Subset a dataframe using a logical vector with $

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I'm having trouble understanding both the **reason for use** and **behavior** of the `$` symbol in subsetting a `data.frame` in R. The following example was presented in a beginner's class I'm taking (not with a live professor so can't ask there):

```
temp_mat <- matrix(1:9, nrow=3)
colnames(temp_mat) <- c('a', 'b', 'c')
temp_df <- data.frame(temp_mat)
```

Calling `temp_df` obviously outputs:

```
  a b c
1 1 4 7
2 2 5 8
3 3 6 9
```

The example given in the course is then:

```
temp_df[temp_df$c < 10]
```

Which outputs:

```
  a b c
1 1 4 7
2 2 5 8
3 3 6 9
```

**Reason for use question:** The course indicates that `$` is used for partial matching, and that `x$y` is an exact substitute for `x[["y", exact=FALSE]]`. Why would we want to use a partial matching operator here? Do we use it because we know for sure that in our `temp_df` there is no other column similar to "c" that could be mistakenly picked up? Additionally, how is partial match measured? A minimum % of characters matching or something? It appears there is a `getElement` function that would be much more appropriate if working with datasets with unknown or similar column names (e.g. Home Phone versus Cell Phone, would these be seen as a valid partial match?)

**Behavior question:** it appears the above example `temp_df[temp_df$c < 10]` is saying "return the subset of elements from temp_df where column c is less than 10" and because all column c elements meet the criteria, the entire dataframe is returned. My interpretation is obviously wrong because `temp_df[temp_df$c < 9]` returns:

```
  a b
1 1 4
2 2 5
3 3 6
```

Although the row 1 and 2 elements in column c do meet the criteria of being less than 9, the entire column is omitted. My question then becomes twofold: what is that logical vector actually saying/doing? And how would I write my interpretation of "return the subset of elements from temp_df where column c is less than 9" and have it return:

```
  a b c
1 1 4 7
2 2 5 8
```

Because in my mind, elements 1 and 2 (rows 1 and 2) met that criteria as their column c values are less than 9 and thus should be returned.

Comment: Try `temp_df[temp_df$c < 9, ]` with a comma to disambiguate indexing.

Comment: makes sense, now it's saying rows where column c is less than 9. Why is the default to act on the columns when there is no comma, despite rows coming first in the []?

Comment: It is because the best way to think about a data-frame is as a special kind of `list`, with the column names as keys and the column contents as vector values. The default behavior operates on this principle and drops keys (i.e. columns) marked `FALSE`.

Comment: In my opinion, no course should teach the example `temp_df[temp_df$c < 10]` -- such an operation would never be useful.

Comment: I agree Frank, understanding now it doesn't seem useful at all. As a follow-up, why use the $ operator at all? If i had a dataset with similarly named columns I wouldn't want to leave the exact match to chance

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try breaking down the operation in steps.

```
temp_df$c < 9
```

gives a vector as follows:

```
[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

When you pass this vector in the manner you have shown:
`temp_df[c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE)]` has the effect of operating on columns.

Think about a `data.frame` as a list, with column names as the keys and the column contents as vector values. The operation preserves the TRUE keys (i.e. columns) and drops the FALSE.

The comma serves to mark the vector as row index. The first two rows are retained and the last one is dropped. Thus, `temp_df[c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE), ]` gives:

```
  a b c
1 1 4 7
2 2 5 8
```

Comment: This is wonderful - I knew my confusion came from a fundamental misunderstanding of the behavior of the `data.frame` structure so this is immensely helpful. Your breaking down of the operation is an excellent lesson that'll help me answer my own questions going forward. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Both the `$` and `[[` are `extract` operator which allows to extract elements by name.

OP has raised one query about behavior of `exact` argument. The `exact` argument of the `[[` operator has been documented in `RStudio` as:

> Controls possible partial matching of [[ when extracting by a
>   character vector (for most objects, but see under ‘Environments’). The
>   default is no partial matching. Value NA allows partial matching but
>   issues a warning when it occurs. Value FALSE allows partial matching
>   without any warning.

What does it mean? To understand its behavior lets change the `column names` of data.frame used by OP as:

```
names(temp_df) <- c("aa","bb","cc")

#partial name of column will work with exact = FALSE
temp_df[["a", exact = FALSE]]
#[1] 1 2 3
#partial name of column will not work with exact = TRUE
temp_df[["a", exact = TRUE]]
#NULL
temp_df[["a", exact = NA]]
#[1] 1 2 3
#Warning message:
#In .subset2(x, i, exact = exact) : partial match of 'a' to 'aa'
```

Comment: This is helpful and I understand it. My follow-up question would be: why did my instructor choose to use $ in our case? We know the column was labelled c. If i were to have a dataset with "Home Phone" and "Cell Phone" columns, I would never want to use $ and risk grabbing the wrong column. I could see an application for $ where i'm looking for common values between two lists of different source (e.g. one says Tiger while another says Bengal Tiger), but I'm wondering what the advantage was of using $ in the course example.

Comment: @RichardGolz The `$` is very handy to use. Think of cases like `df$Name`, `df$Amount` or `df$AccountNumber` where it will be easier to use `$`. Even you can use something like `temp_df$'Home Phone'` and so on.

Comment: Are you saying `df$AccountNumber` would be useful if the dataset had an account number column, but you weren't sure what it's called? For example it could be "Account#" or "Account number" or "AccountNumber"

Comment: Also, with `temp_df$"Home Phone"` might you be risking picking up the "Cell Phone" column?

Comment: @RichardGolz Not really. I'm saying that `$` allows use to easily select data of a column of data.frame. Again, with `$` you are not using `partial` names anyway. You are expected to provide full name with `$`. Hence its more restrictive. Now if someone want to use `partial` names just to avoiding typing longnames they can do so using `exact` attributes.

Comment: in the R documentation it states that `x$y` is equivalent to `x[["y", exact=FALSE]]`. Am I confusing 'partial' versus `exact=FALSE`?  It appears that `x$y` may pick up column names similar to y but not necessarily exactly y, making `$` unreliable

Comment: @RichardGolz You are absolutely correct. `$` supports partial name. But if there are two columns which satisfy partial `name` then `NULL` is returned. Hence, in practice one should use full name. Suppose a dataframe got columns as `AAA` and `AAAA`. Then `df$AA` will return NULL but `df$AAA` will return value from `AAA` column.

Comment: Thank you - it supports partial name but returns NULL if multiple names fit the criteria. Apologies for the extended questioning, I'm a newbie. But you helped a lot